# .cshtml File containing 'at' symbol with curly brackets; What is this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am starting to work with the asp.net web framework. I have a .cshtml file that someone has previously written and it contains a bit of code that I cannot find any information on:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Watching " + Model.EventName;
    int eventId = Model.Id;
}
```

From what I can tell, the above code creates c# variables that can be referenced by internal javascript e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    someJavaScriptFunction(@eventId);
</script>
```

What is this 'technique' called?

Comment: That's the Razor, uh layout engine or something. Google ASP.NET Razor and you'll find it.

Comment: Inside of the brackets you can use C#/Razor code, like declaring an `int eventId = Model.Id;` as you have.

Comment: The JavaScript isn't referencing those variables. `@eventId` outputs the value of `eventId` to the page that is being served.

Comment: I suggest you obtain a book or tutorial on ASP.NET MVC. If you haven't read some kind of materials to acquaint yourself with this platform, you're going to find yourself extremely lost trying to stumble through it.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client. Not on the server, so it can't directly reference C# variables. However, when the Razor view gets rendered you can inject values from C# variables into the resulting markup (including JavaScript if you have that in your view). The difference is subtle but important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view the [Razor syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor) you'll find that

> Razor supports C# and uses the @ symbol to transition from HTML to C#.

so when you see

```
@{ }
```

It is a C# (server side only) code block.  It's important to understand that all cshtml (c#) runs first and only pure html/css/javascript hits the client.  So code like the following does not make sense:

```
@{
  var a = 1;
}

function blah(){
  var b = @a;
  b++;
  @a = b;
}
```

because it will compile literally into:

```
function blah(){
  var b = 1;
  b++;
  1 = b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is this code between `@{ }`?

`@{ }` delineates a section of C# code that you can place in the .cshtml file, which will execute as the page is being rendered. In this case, it's placing an entry in the `ViewData` collection and assigning a value to the `eventId` variable.

> How is a C# variable being used in JavaScript code?

Here again the `@` indicates Razor code. `@variable` will output the value of `variable` to the page, so supposing `eventId` had the value `12`, the page would actually be rendered with:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    someJavaScriptFunction(12);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a name for the technique other than 'dynamic output of javascript argument with Razor and C#'.

Answer (score 0):

*from your description i'm assuming the @{} is not actually your main question, so iv decided to explain the content within*

the viewdata and or viewbag are dynamic objects, this means you can set the objects properties in the view or controller,... the model object is the object that you decide to pass to the view for rendering.

basically viewdata and or viewbag allow you to set values to them in the view or in the controller,

so:

```
 ViewData["Title"] = "Watching " + Model.EventName;
```

will set the title property to the corresponding string value, the Viewbag.title property is usually in the layout.cshtml - so once this view is passed from the controller , the title value will be set to "Watching " + Model.EventName;

frankly its important because -  you can set properties on the fly after other views are called

model.ID - is the id of the object you pass to the view - so if you pass the movie object to view it will render the stored properties of that object

controller - >

```
movie model = new movie() {title = 'Tommy boy'};
view(model)
```

View ->

```
<html><p>@Model.title <p> </html> is = <html><p>Tommy boy</p></html>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx